# Catch error not failing nightwatchjs test

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-status-codes, nightwatch.js

I'm using nightwatchjs to run a 'smoke' test of URLs in order to ensure that they are reporting back a 200 status code.

Within this test I'm using the **[axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)** and **[xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)** npm packages to read a list of URLs from a spreadsheet and test the status code.

Here is my test code;

```
 var XLSX = require('xlsx');
 var workbook = XLSX.readFile('./dmokeURLs.xlsx');
 var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
 var xlData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]]);
 var xcelData = xlData.map(item => { return item.URL; });

 module.exports = {
    '@tags': ['smokeTestURLs'],
     'Testing for status code': async (browser) => {
        async function xcelUrlArr(item) {
            var response = await axios.get(browser.launch_url + item);
            browser.assert.equal(response.status, 200);
        }
        for (let index = 0; index < xcelData.length; index++) {
             var adsTexturl = xcelData[index];
             await xcelUrlArr(adsTexturl);
        }
    },
    'Closing browser': function (browser)  {
        browser.browserEnd();
    },
};
```

This works fine, when the URLs return a 200 status code.

However, when there is an error the following is returned...

[image]

but the test still passes.

What I'd like to do is fail the actual nightwatchjs test whenever an error is thrown.

Is this possible, and if so how would I go about doing this?

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You explicitly catch (and then only log) the error. If you want it to fail the test, either don't catch it or re-raise it.

Comment: Thanks for you reply @jonrsharpe but not sure I understand when you say 'don't catch' the error. Do you mean remove the catch part of the try/catch altogether? Thanks.

Comment: Remove the `try` entirely. If the error from the assertion should cause the test to fail, don't prevent it from propagating.

Comment: Ok, so I removed everything from `async function xcelUrlArr(item) {` to `for (let index = 0; index < xcelData.length; index++) {` but when the test picks up an error (for example a 404), the test still passes as the _OK. 4  total assertions passed. (4.723s)_ message is displayed, even though the _(node:41173) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 404_ message is generated. Any ideas how I can get Nightwatch to 'interpret' this as an *error* and fail the test. Many thanks

Comment: Please [edit] to show the updated [mre].

Comment: Ah thanks @jonrsharpe I'd not edited a post before. Have now updated original test script with try code removed. Many thanks.